# custom shelf script not running when maya is launched -error

Tags: python, maya

I want to create a custom shelf at startup in Maya 2018. I am calling a script to build the shelf in a userSetup.py file.  The script will create the shelf if run in the script editor after launch, but throws an error when called on startup.

```
#userSetup.py
#-----
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/alfredwinters/Desktop/python/scripts/')
import lighting_tools_shelf
cmds.evalDeferred("lighting_tools_shelf")

#lighting_tools_shelf.py
#----
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.shelfLayout("lighting_shelf", p="ShelfLayout")
```

**This is the error I get when calling the script at launch.**

Failed to execute userSetup.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/alfredwinters/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2018/scripts/userSetup.py", line 8, in 
import lighting_tools_shelf

File "/Users/alfredwinters/Desktop/python/scripts/lighting_tools_shelf.py", line 19, in custom_shelf
    cmds.shelfLayout(name, p="ShelfLayout")

RuntimeError: shelfLayout: Object 'ShelfLayout' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not mentioned the error while calling `cmds.shelfLayout(name, p="ShelfLayout")`

```
RuntimeError: shelfLayout: Object 'ShelfLayout' not found.
```

It simply saying the **ShelfLayout** object is not available in the given context.
The **ShelfLayout** represents the main layout holding all the Maya Shelves. But it should not be used as it is. You should have to get it from the global variables.

Example:

```
import maya.mel as mel
main_shelf = mel.eval('$tempMelVar=$gShelfTopLevel')

# Now main_shelf holds complete path the the layout
# Now you can use it as parent for other shelf layouts
cmds.shelfLayout(name, p=main_shelf)
```

Hope this will resolve your issue. 
Thanks